# Problema con visualización de código

Tags: bug, estado-por-diseño

Hace unos minutos he respondido a una pregunta. La respuesta es [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/15294/7242), en [la revisión 1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/15294/1):

```
2 cosas. 

1. El `Remove` sólo elimina el primer elemento, para eliminar todas las coincidencias necesitas utilizar el `RemoveAll` ([documentación][1]).

2. Otra buena opción es utilizar linq para hacerlo:

    List<string> Strings2 = Strings.Select(x => x != "123")

  [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx
```

En el texto he añadido este código:

```cs
List<string> Strings2 = Strings.Select(x => x != "123")
```

En mi respuesta se ve así:

2. Otra buena opción es utilizar linq para hacerlo:

   List Strings2 = Strings.Select(x => x != "123")

En esta pregunta sí aparece bien pero no en mi respuesta, ¿Qué he echo mal o qué está pasando? ¿Tiene algo que ver que esté dentro de un `tag` de numeraciones?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo doy formato al código en mis publicaciones?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4039/c%c3%b3mo-doy-formato-al-c%c3%b3digo-en-mis-publicaciones)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando utilizas numeración, debes cambiar alguna de estas opciones:

- 4 espacios.
- Un tabulador ***(	)***.

Por alguna de las siguientes opciones:

- 8 espacios.
- 4 espacios y un tabulador *(1 tab)*.
- Un tabulador y 4 espacios.
- Dos tabuladores *(2 tabs)*.

---

#### Una vez hecho esto, se verá así:

1. Este es
2. Un ejemplo

   De un fragmento

   ```
   console.log("de código")
   ```

¿Se comprende cómo funcionan los espacios y tabuladores en la numeración y lista de elementos?

Ejemplo tomado de la ayuda de resaltado de código:

> Para crear texto con formato previo, aplica una sangría de cuatro
>   espacios o un tabulador. De manera predeterminada se activa el resaltado de sintaxis:
>
> ```
> En este caso, se infiere el tipo del lenguaje, 
>   no necesariamente acertando en el correcto:
>
> console.log("¡Hola mundo!")
> ```
>
> Pero si se quiere eliminar el resaltado (el coloreado), se debe insertar la siguiente etiqueta:
>
> <!-- language: lang-none -->
>
> De esta manera queda el código sin resaltado de sintaxis:
>
> ```
> Esto se muestra en una fuente monoespaciada. Dependiendo del nivel en donde
>   se encuentre el código, se descarta un tabulador o cuatro espacios
>   por cada nivel, y todo lo que esté a la derecha se va mostrando, 
>   incluso cuando en HTML no se muestra más de un espacio seguido,
>   en la parte del código son visibles estos espacios.
>
> Markdown y HTML se desactivan en los bloques de código:
>
>   <i>Esto no está en cursiva</i> y [esto no es un enlace](http://ejemplo.com)
> ```
>
> Para crear un intervalo de código insertado, y no un bloque, utiliza
>   acentos graves (tildes invertidas):
>
> El carácter `$` es un método abreviado para `window.jQuery`.
>
> Si deseas incluir un bloque con formato previo en una lista, aplica
>   una sangría de ocho espacios o dos tabuladores:
>
> 1. Esto es texto normal.
> 2. Esto también, pero ahora le sigue a un bloque de código:
>
>    ```
>    Omite una línea y aplica una sangría de ocho espacios o dos tabuladores.
>
>      Son cuatro espacios o un tabulador para la lista, 
>      y cuatro espacios o un tabulador más para desencadenar el bloque de código.
>    ```

Comment: Gracias por la explicación, llevo mucho tiempo con SO y no lo sabía... cada día se aprende algo. Un saludo!