# ¿Cómo coloco un bloque de código después de una lista?

Tags: soporte, formato

No es posible agregar un bloque de codigo (el bloque que se forma poniendo 4 espacios) justo despues de una lista.

Ejemplo:

- Item

  Esto está detrás de 4 espacios y no se ve como esto de abajo.

Debe haber un párrafo normal para que funcione.

```
Esto está detrás de 4 espacios y se ve correctamente.
```

**Puede comprobarse tocando editar en esta pregunta.**

Otro caso donde se usó un *StackSnippet* como *workaround (no siendo codigo ejecutable)*:

- [¿Cómo cambiar el color de un checkbox?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/60520)

Comment: Propongo cambiar [meta-tag:bug] por [meta-tag:soporte]. La razón la explico en mi [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1678/65), además y en mi humilde opinión, la [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1677/65) de Luiggi concuerda con esto.

Comment: El tema es que necesitás alguna sintaxis para seguir con otro párrafo dentro del mismo ítem de la lista. Y me imagino que es más frecuente seguir dentro del mismo ítem que poner código independiente. Está bien que se necesite un separador, como se muestra en las respuestas. Entiendo que claramente es *por diseño*.

Comment: Mariano, si se necesitan 8 espacios para incluirlo como parte del item, entonces con 4 espacios deberia estar al margen izquierdo y no es lo que sucede, queda como un bloque de texto normal, eso no es natural/intuitivo. Si fuere por diseño, resulta un diseño no natural/intuitivo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema con visualización de código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/658/problema-con-visualizaci%c3%b3n-de-c%c3%b3digo)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo doy formato al código en mis publicaciones?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4039/c%c3%b3mo-doy-formato-al-c%c3%b3digo-en-mis-publicaciones)

Answer (score 8):

Funciona usando alguna de estas alternativas:

- 8 espacios.
- 4 espacios y un tabulador.
- Un tabulador y 4 espacios.
- Dos tabuladores.

> Nota: Esto es porque el código tiene que estar al nivel siguiente de donde se encuentra actualmente, entonces el ítem es el primer nivel, y el código el segundo nivel. Hay un nivel cada 4 espacios o un tabulador ya que 4 espacios es equivalente a un tabulador (no vale poner 2 espacios, un tabulador y luego 2 espacios).

Ejemplo:

- Aquí un elemento de lista:

  ```java
  public class UnaClase {
      /* definición de la clase */
  }
  ```

  Explicación del código anterior.
- Otro elemento de la lista.

---

Si lo que quieres es agregar una lista y luego agregar código, puedes usar `<!-- -->` para separar los párrafos.

Ejemplo:

- Oración 1
- Oración 2

```
Mi código va aquí.
```

- Oración 3

Aunque si vas a colocar código entre elementos de una lista, recomiendo la primera opción.

Comment: Gracias x el workaround, pero creo que esto es lo que hay que hacer si se quiere que el bloque de codigo sea parte del item de la lista (entiendase que este identado al mismo nivel que el item de lista), pero no es util si lo que se quiere es que sea un bloque de codigo independiente, identado a la izquierda.

Comment: No lo veo como workaround. En realidad, usas 4 espacios para indicar que el texto está al mismo nivel que el elemtno de tu lista. Sobre eso, usas 4 espacios más para agregar código que es parte de la lista.

Comment: Concuerdo, es un feature, pero es para otro caso.

Comment: Creo haber entendido el problema. Ahí mandé un update.

Comment: Sobre la edición, es lo mismo que puso @Ruben y sirve como alternativa, gracias!

Comment: Ah, no había visto su respuesta.

Comment: Oh! me pasó ayer mismo y no sabia `<!-- -->` hahah

Answer (score 5):

No se trata de un bug, sino de una característica debido al soporte de markdown. Hay varias soluciones. A continuación muestro el uso de la etiqueta comentario en HTML `<!--...-->`

Markdown:

```
- Elemento

<!-- -->

    Codigo
```

Resultado:

- Elemento

```
Codigo
```

Comment: Esto o `<code>`