# ¿Cómo doy formato al código en mis publicaciones?

Tags: soporte, faq, formato

> <sub>Traducción libre de [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/209901), de Meta.SE</sub>

¿Cómo puedo dar formato a mi texto para que aparezca como código?

¿Cómo hago para que mi código se muestre bien en mi publicación? ¿Cómo consigo el resaltado de sintaxis correcto?

> Para más información, mira en [¿Cómo darle formato a mis publicaciones utilizando Markdown o HTML?](//es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)" en el [Centro de Ayuda](//es.meta.stackoverflow.com/help).

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Código en línea (para código que no contiene saltos de línea)

- Cuando el cursor no está en la primera columna, o has seleccionado texto que no contiene saltos líneas, usa el botón de código `{}`  que aparece en el editor.
- Utiliza backticks: `` `<html>` ``
- Incrusta dentro de las etiquetas `<code>`, y codifica manualmente las entidades HTML: `<code>&lt;html&gt;</code>`
- Selecciona el fragmento de texto y presione <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>K</kbd>  (<kbd>Comando</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> o  <kbd>⌘</kbd>   <kbd>K</kbd>  en OS X)

### Bloques de código (conserva líneas nuevas)

- Cuando el cursor está en la primera columna, o si has seleccionado texto que incluye una nueva línea, use el botón de código `{}` sobre el editor.
- Pega tu código, seleccione las líneas completas y presiona <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>K</kbd>  ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   <kbd>K</kbd> , o  <kbd>⌘</kbd>   <kbd>K</kbd>  en OS X)
- Sangrar todo cuatro (4) espacios.
- Aumenta la sangría en las líneas seleccionadas con <kbd>TAB</kbd>, disminúyela con  <kbd>MAYÚS</kbd>  +  <kbd>TAB</kbd>
- Encierra con etiquetas `<pre>` o `<pre> <code>` (en ese orden; [el uso de `<code> <pre>` no es válido](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128477/display-error-when-nesting-pre-in-code-elements/128480#128480)), y codifica las entidades HTML (como `& lt;`para`<`) tú mismo.

El código copiado / pegado desde un IDE a menudo contiene tabulaciones. Al renderizar, los tabulados se sustituyen por espacios. Sin embargo, debes eliminar los tabulados del código que has pegado en caso de que otros tengan que aplicar un formato adicional.

[image: Icono de bloqueo de código correctamente resaltado]

### Dentro de un código de citación

Debes sangrar otros cuatro espacios por cada nivel de anidación.

```
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

> para (;;)
        eco 'currupipi';
```

### Dentro de una lista

Debes sangrar otros cuatro espacios para cada nivel de anidación.

```
- Primer punto (la más profunda)

        para(;;)
          echo 'ow';

- Segundo punto
```

### Resaltado de sintaxis

[Prettify](//code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) se usa para agregar color al código, pero [solo si](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72391/why-isnt-syntax-highlighting-working-in-a-question) el idioma puede determinarse de manera única dadas las etiquetas de la pregunta, o si se han proporcionado sugerencias manuales en comentarios HTML, usando:

```
<!-- language: lang-o-etiqueta -->

    aquí va el código

<!-- language: lang-o-etiqueta -->

    aquí va el código
```

También puede especificar la sintaxis para *todos* los bloques de código en su publicación con la sugerencia `language-all`:

```
<!-- language-all: lenguaje-o-etiqueta -->

    el código va aquí

Texto que no pertenece a bloque de código

    el código va aquí
```

Consulte [la especificación completa](//es.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) y [lista de sugerencias de idiomas](//es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1464/83).

Ten en cuenta que:

- Los comentarios HTML deben *no* ser sangrados
 - Se requiere la línea en blanco entre `<! - idioma: ... ->` y el bloque de código con sangría * *
 - El espacio entre `language:` y el idioma es requerido
 - Al usar una etiqueta para especificar el idioma, el nombre de la etiqueta es *distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas*.

Si no se define ningún idioma, entonces no se produce ningún resaltado. Pero en la vista previa, o si las etiquetas de varios idiomas definen idiomas muy diferentes y no se usa una definición manual, se usa un resaltado predeterminado en el que Prettify hace una mejor estimación.

Hay un retraso antes de que se aplique el resaltado del texto de la vista previa después de que deje de editar su fuente de reducción, de alrededor de 5 segundos.

### En dispositivos móviles

- A veces es necesario [mantener presionada](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133673/is-there-a-way-to-enter-back-tick-backtick-on-so-when-using-ipad-or-iphone) la comilla simple regular para obtener el backtick.

### Backticks en el texto

- Para incluir un backtick sin iniciar accidentalmente algún código en línea, escápalo: `\` 
      ``` - `` like \ ```soproduce: like ` so
      - `` <kbd> Alt Gr </kbd> + <kbd> \ `</kbd> obtiene` | `` `produce: <kbd> Alt Gr </kbd> + <kbd> \`  obtiene `|`

### Backticks dentro de Backticks

- Para usar backticks literales dentro de un intervalo de código, [usa cualquier *número* único de múltiples backticks](//daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code) como delimitadores de apertura y cierre: ambos  `literal backtick (`) aquí ``` y por ejemplo, `` `` `` `` ```literal backtick (```````` ) here``````` `` ````````produceliteral backtick (`) here``. Esto [funciona en comentarios también](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oAaC.png).
- Para usar backticks literales al inicio y / o final, añade *un* espacio a los delimitadores de apertura y de cierre:  `<html>`  `produce` `<html>` `, y`  $  `` `produce el operador Perl` `$` ``. En los comentarios, el espacio adicional en los delimitadores no es compatible. En su lugar, escape la comilla:  \ `<html> \`  `y`   `para obtener` `<html>` `o` $ `` `[en un comentario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msVOx.png).

### Fragmento de código

Agrega un código de código haciendo clic en el botón de la barra de herramientas de JavaScript / HTML / CSS o  <kbd>CTRL  +  M</kbd> . Esto insertará el siguiente texto que se puede editar con el editor de fragmentos de código (aparecerá un enlace en la vista previa * edita el fragmento de código anterior *).

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->
//javascript goes here
<!-- language: lang-css -->
.css .goes .here {background-color: blue;}
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<div>html goes here</div>
<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: ¿Crees que algún día StackExchange haga su propio resaltador de sintaxis en vez de usar Prettify? No se qué tan difícil sea que implementen un resaltado de markdown, con la extrema complejidad que llevaría eso.

Comment: @ArtEze lo veo complicado y poco necesario, francamente.

Comment: ¿Viste que cambiaron los íconos para editar las publicaciones y ahora son todos grises? Quizás se podría adaptar [esta imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCW2k.png) a como se ve ahora y además en español, pero no tengo instalado algún programa que dibuje flechas (no tengo espacio en disco).

Comment: Gracias, @ArtEze. Lo apunto en la lista de cosas que querría hacer