# Mejor manera de insertar código en una pregunta

Tags: soporte, formato

Soy nuevo en stackoverflow.

Quisiera saber cómo insertar código, en este caso sentencias sql, sin que dé error en la publicación.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? Puedes leer [¿Cómo doy formato al código en mis publicaciones?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4039/83)